# Incorrectly uploaded file?

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm running windows and have a function in C# that gets the rows of a csv file:

```
List<string> getRows(System.IO.Stream, out long)
```

I am trying to upload a local file using the following:

```
using (FileStream csvFile = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\ME\Documents\test.csv"))
{
  long s2 = csvFile.Length;
  var rows = getRows(csvFile, s2);
}
```

This gives me an error that I am passing invalid arguments to the getRows method. I even tried casting the csvFile to explicitly make it of type System.IO.Stream:

```
using (FileStream csvFile = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\ME\Documents\testUpload.csv"))
{
  long s2 = csvFile.Length;
  System.IO.Stream casted_csvFile = (System.IO.Stream) csvFile;
  var rows = getRows(casted_csvFile, s2);
}
```

Am I uploading the file incorrectly? Am I misusing the System.IO.Stream type?

Comment: Where are you trying to upload this?

Comment: You have missed the `out` keyword when calling the method.

Comment: Why all the down votes, please? I am new to this site and want to improve the quality of my questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a method that accepts an `out` parameter:

```
public void Foo(out long bar)
{
    ....
}
```

When calling that method you have to use the `out` keyword:

```
long bar;
Foo(out bar);
```

Comment: Did you read the question? From the first line "List<string> getRows(System.IO.Stream, out long)"

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! I'll vote up when SO lets me!

Comment: @arserbin3 I updated the question to make it clearer. It was kind of hidden in there.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Kelley's answer is more helpful for others having this problem in the future.

However, in your particular case, there should be no need to have that length parameter as an `out` variable.

Instead of adding `out` when calling it, you should change the signature to:

```
List<string> getRows(System.IO.Stream stream, long length)
```

removing the `out` altogether.